# Unknown class <MyViewController> in Interface Builder file + Localization issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, localization

I have an app with two localizations.
Usually I use 'NSLocalizedString' and keep the same source code for both localizations, but one of my ViewControllers has to look and function different for each locale.
So I pressed 'Localize..' and created two localized versions of it. Normal stuff.

Since then - on runtime I get:

> Unknown class MyViewController in Interface Builder file.

and the viewcontroller is not displayed (it's a UITableViewController if it matters).
I checked in my storyboard and the custom class is still listed & linked to the view controller display. I didn't change the class name in each locale - it's still the same.

what gives here?

thanks

Comment: I'm stuck. anyone??? :-(

Answer (score 3):

i experimented this kind of problem in my project and my problem was my viewcontrollers .m file was not included in the compile sources in Build Phases->Compile Sources i manually add it to the Compile Sources and problem solved for me.
i hope it will help you.

Comment: super duper, you save my day!